# BackgroundSession error in Xcode when going to foreground

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode things and I am developing an app for iOS but every time when I go with app in background and then foreground I get this bunch of logs which I don't really get what is this about. I use Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.4 on real device

Can please anyone explain this to me and if I have to worry about it?

Thanks in advance

```
2021-02-13 14:58:20.054134+0000 client[39062:2633944] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x12589d600, UIKeyboardImpl) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
2021-02-13 14:58:24.515697+0000 client[39062:2659753] BackgroundSession <74966452-3645-4A40-8BCB-66D38983CDB4> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-02-13 14:58:24.515906+0000 client[39062:2659752] BackgroundSession <9CA7A573-AE28-44C4-A04F-45FB8B993F32> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-02-13 14:58:24.521576+0000 client[39062:2659634] BackgroundSession <420CD208-D168-4CFC-AF79-DEBD0A907D23> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-02-13 14:58:24.523285+0000 client[39062:2659634] BackgroundSession <D616FF8F-251A-4728-90F1-4099BC79913C> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-02-13 14:58:24.524281+0000 client[39062:2659758] BackgroundSession <9CA7A573-AE28-44C4-A04F-45FB8B993F32> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-02-13 14:58:24.525739+0000 client[39062:2659746] BackgroundSession <420CD208-D168-4CFC-AF79-DEBD0A907D23> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-02-13 14:58:24.525969+0000 client[39062:2659760] BackgroundSession <D616FF8F-251A-4728-90F1-4099BC79913C> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-02-13 14:58:24.526011+0000 client[39062:2659633] BackgroundSession <74966452-3645-4A40-8BCB-66D38983CDB4> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-02-13 14:58:24.541147+0000 client[39062:2659070] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C933] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```